# Copy a section of text using a regex pattern c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use this to copy a section of text from another but it doesn't quite work.

Is there another regex command where it can copy text from another based on the pattern provided? I saw Regex match is that the one?

```
mystring = Regex.Split(my_other_string, @"(?<=\[Start\]).*(?=\[End\])");
```

Don't think my regex pattern is quite correct either.

I need to copy all text between [Start] and [End]

The text looks like:
[Start]
Hellooo World
[End]

But the pattern does not return anything:

```
(?<=\[Start\]).*(?=\[End\])
```

Comment: `Regex.Split`? I think you're searching for `Regex.Match` to get the value denoted by `.*`

Comment: `Regex.Match` is the one you're lookin for

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Regex.Match` - Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the Regex constructor.  (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)